# What are ideal /etc/passwd file permissions?

Tags: file-permissions, passwd

Is there any risk keeping open world-read access to passwd file?
Why is by default passwd file world-readable

Answer (score 11):

It is for all users to be able to read their usernames and other data in this file. Sensitive data in modern UNIX systems is kept in `/etc/shadow` file.

Answer (score 5):

/etc/passwd is world-readable because it contains system-wide account information, like username to real name mappings.  It doesn't contain password hashes; those are in /etc/shadow which is only readable by root.  Anything that needs to do authentication has to go through a trusted setuid-root service that can check that file.

(And, of course, many systems don't use passwd/shadow for account information anymore.  If you use the C library instead of reading the files directly, though, you won't notice.)

Answer (score 3):

The passwd file doesn't contain password hashes any more - they are in the shadow file.

/etc/passwd now only contains the list of users on the computer, and a few basic parameters like their shell. The reason to make it world-readable is so that the world can read it.

This is not generally considered a security vulnerability, though in some circumstances it may be inappropriate.